# GIT Branch has not shown for merging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, tortoisegit

I have a 1 branch on my GIT repository.It is `V-1.9.1.1`

[image]

So I need to merge `V-1.9.1.1` into `Master`.But it doesn't show such branch on my local copy when I use the TortoiseGit windows tool.Could you tell me why it has not being shown there ? Thanks.

[image]

When I go to branch copy on my local machine then it shows like this.There I think it's fine.But I need to merge from `V-1.9.1.1` to `Master`.Could you tell me what is the problem here ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you are checkout on branch V-1.9.1.1. You cannot merge branch to itself and that's why you don't see `V-1.9.1.1`. Try to checkout master and then merge `V-1.9.1.1` into `master` as you want...

if you want to try it from command line, take the following steps:

```
git checkout master
git merge V-1.9.1.1
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

In TortoiseGit: goto your repository directory, right click 'Switch/Checkout' and select 'master' branch:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the commands.Could you tell me how to do that with `TortoiseGit windows tool` ? Step by step. Thanks.

Comment: What did you mean  `goto your repository directory` ? Is that my local copy of `master` or `branch` ? Thanks.

Comment: Your code has main/root directory. If you clone it from github and your github repository url for example is https://github.com/<user>/project1 so you have directory called project1 somewhere in your file system. I'm talking about this directory

Comment: Do I need to `clone` to use above ? I have used create repository option and then pull from the master.Is that wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: No. You clone only once. all branches are maintained in the same local repository. Just try to find that directory that I was taking about above and right click on it. You'll see the TortoiseGit options like in the screenshot

Comment: Ok,When I select the master as you said above then it gives this message `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Already on 'master'` What can I do now ? Thanks.

Comment: Great. In the same place there is 'pull' option as well (first one). Try to pull updates from remote repository (github) and then try your merge again. By the way, are you working on this github repository alone or there are more contributors?

Comment: I'm the only contributor :D

Comment: What did you mean this `Try to pull updates from remote repository` ? Is this from the Branch ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but if you are the only contributor it redundant. I do need to see the different between the two screenshots that you have added in your question (the directories you have hide) I think you are looking at a different repositories.. and it's all the confusion

Comment: Actually I have one repository and one branch as I mentioned on original post.What info do you need from me ? Thanks.

Comment: So you are see the same directory in the hidden line? As I understand you have one repository (as expected) and two branches: master & V-1.9.1.1

Comment: Here it is 1 image : `local-folder-path\Master` 2 image : `local-folder-path\Branch`

Comment: Yes,you're right. i.e. `two branches: master & V-1.9.1.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108827/discussion-between-itayb-and-sampath).

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub you see remote branches which do not have to have a corresponding branch in all your local repositories.

Switch/checkout to your master branch and do

- a fetch and a following manual merge (the remote branch will show up as `remotes/origin/V-1.9.1.1`) or
- a pull the `V-1.9.1.1` branch from the remote repository (pull = fetch+merge).

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get what you said.Can you give more info about it ? From where should I pull ? Either from the `master` or `branch` ? Thanks.

Comment: I used the pull option you have mentioned above.Then it deleted all the folders which are not in the  branch `V-1.9.1.1` no ? That is not what I need.I need to keep extra folders and files which are not in the branch and merge only the items which are on both places.So how can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These commands might help you.
The sequence is

First get latest copy of V-1.9.1.1

Then, checkout master branch

And then, perform merge on master branch with V-1.9.1.1 branch.

```
git pull origin V-1.9.1.1 
git checkout master
git merge V-1.9.1.1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the commands.Could you tell me how to do that with `TortoiseGit windows tool` ? Step by step. Thanks.